# Binding list difficulty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My difficulty here is how to do the part shown "How to do the part?"

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Test { public Test() 
    {   
        Name = "Test";
        Subs = new List<Sub>(); 
        Subs.Add(new Sub { Num = 1, SubName = "A", Valid=false }); 
        Subs.Add(new Sub { Num = 2, SubName = "B" , Valid= true}); }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public List<Sub> Subs { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Sub { 
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public string SubName { get; set; }
        public bool Valid { get; set; }
    } 

}
```

View:

```
 @model MvcApplication1.Models.Test

@{
    View.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    var i = 0;
    }
}

    <h2>Test2</h2>  
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
     {      
        <p>Test Name</p>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)  
        foreach(var item in Model.Subs)    
        <p>Sub 1</p>


        @Html.EditorFor(m => item[i].Num)<------
             @Html.EditorFor(m => item[i].SubName**)<------How to do this part?**     
       @Html.EditorFor(m => item[i++].Valid**)



      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        return View(test);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Test test)
    {
        return View(test);
    }

}
```

Comment: You did not explain what you expect to show up for subname??! I ended up writing half an answer before I realized that. Please add a more clearer explanation of what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could customize the editor template:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{      
    <p>Test Name</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)  
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subs)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Sub.cshtml`):

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Sub
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Num)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubName)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Valid)
```